# Laravel: show categories and products tree wise

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to show the categories and products as tree wise means subsequent products will be shown under the category and so on. To create this, I made this script which shows only categories but no products appearing under it. Below is my script for the controller:

```
$data['sitecategories'] = $this->generateSiteCategorySubcategory(-1);
```

In the same controller, I have created the function:

```
public function generateSiteCategorySubcategory($startAt) {
        if ($children = Sitecategory::getCategorySubcategory($startAt)) {
            $thisLevel = array();
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $thisLevel[$child->id] = $child;
                $thisLevel[$child->id]->children = $this->generateSiteCategorySubcategory($child->id);
            }
            return $thisLevel;
        }
    }
```

In the blade I have written to render the products and categories in select box:

```
<select name="categoryid"  class="form-control customSelect" >                                                                                        
 @foreach ($sitecategories as $sitecategory)                                                                                    
 @php if($sitecategory->parentCategoryId != '-1'){ $catName = "--". 
 $sitecategory->categoryName;                                                                                        
 } else { $catName = $sitecategory->categoryName;                                                                                     
}                                                                                    
@endphp
<option value="{{$sitecategory->id}}">{{$catName}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Below is the db table structure:

id       parentCategoryId               categoryName             status

---

1        -1                             Tablets & Phones          1

2        -1                             Fashion                   1

10        1                             Phone                     1

12        1                             tablets                   1

15        2                             Women's                   1

Once I run the script, it shows only categories in the select box but no products are appearing under categories.

Comment: Where in your code are you calling the products table?

Comment: @DimitriMostrey there is no product table. The products are denoted with the parentCategoryId which is not -1. category means = -1

Comment: Oh my goodness bro. This seems like a bad idea. You should split it up by making 2 tables with a category_id to products. With respect to the orm/models convention, it will save you a lot of time. And confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.

```
$categoryProducts = \DB::table('categories)
             ->join('products','products.category_id','=','categories.id')
             ->select('categories.*','products.*')
             ->get();

     dd($categoryProducts);
```